# Set up Azure Web App to accept client certificates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application that I deployed to Microsoft Azure as a Web App. In that application I have some Web API endpoints that would be only accessible if the user has the correct certificate with the allowed thumbprint. However, I have other endpoints as well (and of course the website) that would be accessible without a client certificate.

I know there is a possibility to [set up the Azure Web App to require client certificate through a HTTPS connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth). But if I make the mentioned REST API call

> ARMClient PUT subscriptions/{Subscription Id}/resourcegroups/{Resource Group Name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{Website Name}?api-version=2015-04-01 @enableclientcert.json -verbose

that will cause that only those users can visit my site and use the Web API endpoints who has client certificates.

If I open my locally installed IIS Manager, I will have an option to Accept client certificates, not to require them, as you can see in this image:
[image]

My question is how can I set up my Azure Web App to accept (not require) client certificates? I searched over this site and many other forums, but I cannot find a way to set up Web Apps in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

> My question is how can I set up my Azure Web App to accept (not require) client certificates?

It seems that it is not supported on azure now. I also find the [support optional client certificates for TLS mutual auth](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/13481457-support-optional-client-certificates-for-tls-mutua) feedback. And now it is underview by Azure team. You also can vote it up.

<del>We also could remote to the Azure website using IIS Manager to set up it, you could get the detail steps from this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/).</del>

<del>**Prerequisites**

>On Window client OS - [IIS Manager for Remote Administration][3]

>On Windows Server – Make sure you have installed IIS Management Console.
Refer to step 6 in http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7 - “IIS Management Console” is the required feature.</del>

[image]

Comment: thank you for you answer, I haven't thought about connecting to an Azure Web App with IIS Manager. However when I set up my site to Accept client certificate I can no longer reach my site over https, because I got an HTTP 500.0 - Internal Server Error message, with the following relevant detailed error information:
Detailed Error Information:
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification    BeginRequest
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code    0x80070005

Comment: I have updated the answer.  It seems that it is not supported on azure now

Comment: Thanks, it seems its been an issue a while...
Meanwhile I am thinking about using OWIN to get the client certificate from the request data. I can see a key called "ssl.LoadClientCertAsync" that I can maybe use somehow to retrieve the value of the cert...